# Utilize Address ID in Tennent instance as part of the same post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pass the ID of the newly created address as a reference to the Tennent _addressMailing. The addressInstance is supposed to return this ID witch I use in my sequential object creation. I suspect it has something to do with the async handling.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
const address = new Address({
        fullname: data.fullname,
        street1: data.street,
        street2: data.appartment,
        city: data.city,
        state: data.state,
        zipcode: data.zipcode
        })

    const addressInstance = await address.save( (err, address) => {return address._id} );

const tennent = new Tennent({
    name: data.company,
    subdomain: 'test',
    _addressMailing: addressInstance
})

const tennentInstance = await tennent.save();
```

console.log(addressInstance)

Console log output:

```
undefined
```

Database object for tennent:

```
_id: 5d508d8ff6ea5455f07e106f
name:"Digi"
subdomain:"test"
__v:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to get the _id of the new address saved then check if saved then pass it in the new Tennet.

```
const address = new Address({
    fullname: data.fullname,
    street1: data.street,
    street2: data.appartment,
    city: data.city,
    state: data.state,
    zipcode: data.zipcode
    })

 //
 const newAddress = await address.save();
 if(!newAddress) 
  return res.status(400).send({error:" can't create a new address"}); 
  console.log(newAddress);

 const tennent = new Tennent({
   name: data.company,
   subdomain: 'test',
   _addressMailing: newAddress._id
 })

 const tennentInstance = await tennent.save();
```